# running a query on each iteration

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback, node-mysql

Can somebody help me with this query on a returned query?

I want the query to iterate through the results of the previous query to see if a voucher has been used

this is the code for the query :

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID in ?', [(1,2,3,4)],
function(err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err
    var items = []
    rows.forEach(function(i) {
        var item = {
            'item1': i.item1,
            'item2': i.item2,
            'item3': i.item3
        }
        db.query('SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ID = ?', [i.ID],
        function(err, rows2) {
            if (err) throw err
            item.subvalue = rows2
        })
        items.push(item)
        })
        res.json(items)
    })
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is - a returned what? What's the code trying to show? Where about's is the problem you're having in the code?

Comment: `['(1,2,3,4)]` -> `[(1,2,3,4)]`

Comment: the main query is getting a list of items in this case booking for a given month. I then need to iterate through the results and with a second query check if the was a voucher used on each item. both the queries work fine separately i was wanting to know the best method to as the results from the second query on the the object being built in the foreach loop. As i can't just go item.subvalue = rows2

Comment: What's `[(1,2,3,4)]`? I don't think it's correct.

Comment: BTW you can't iterate the results inside the query call because it's asynchronous. You should use a callback or the async module.

Comment: I know mistyped but the issue is how I do the second query with in the iteration of the first queries resiults

Comment: I am still getting used the callbacks still new to me so this probem is I don't the format too yet

Answer (score 0):

So I did this in the end. used multiple statement where the second query returns all possible results need for results in query 1. Then I can iterate through results 1 and results 2 within it.

Still not sure this is the best approach but it works. Any suggestions are very welcome

```
db.query('SELECT 1 WHERE Range ?; SELECT 2 WHERE ID IN (SELECT 1)', 
[req.body.hotelid, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30', 
req.body.hotelid, '2015-11-01', '2015-11-30'],
    function(err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else
            var items = []
        result[0].forEach(function(i) {
            var giftVoucherUsed = []
            var item = {
                'ID': i.BookingID,
                'BookingDate': i.BookingDate,
                'GuestName': 'Guestname'
            }                
            result[1].forEach(function(g){
                if(g.BookingID == i.BookingID){
                    giftVoucherUsed.push(g) 
                }
            })
            item['GiftVoucher'] = giftVoucherUsed

            items.push(item)
        })
       res.json(items)
    });
```